# Microsoft Excel Data Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2013, charts

So I have a lot going on with my current table, I use it for showing my portfolio in a snap:
[image: portfolio in a snap]
Except it's lacking a pretty looking pie chart. Here's the thing, I can do what others have suggested. Just put a hidden category tally with a sum of each blah blah blah, except when I change my portfolio that wouldn't even matter. This thing is changing constantly.

So how can I get excel to be smart, add up my market value's in a specific category and get those into a pie chart. How my chart is currently.
As you can see that thing is ugly as a pie with many of the same labels.
[image: ugly as pie]

Answered by SAM and completed chart for reference.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbiNx.jpg[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PK1hd.png)

Comment: Which Data exactly you want in the Chart, is it the Sum of Us Stock, Foreign... is the Type the Category you want to add

Comment: That is exactly what it is, 4 categories: US Stocks, Foreign, Funds & Bonds.

Comment: You have to make a special table aside from yours, copy the Type and paste 2, 3 columns after the original Table and remove duplicates from it then use sumif to add the data

Comment: @Sam Okay I am not sure I understand, you said make a table aside from mine, by adding a column/s. I now have 2 empty columns B & C. I have created the formula and have a column displaying the us stock data. Should I move this data to the bottom to prevent empty cells? http://imgur.com/I1oAA7R

Comment: Yes you cannot create a Chart with empty cells between Data, I explained with picture in the Answer

Comment: Perfect There is my answer! Thank You so much. http://imgur.com/JaChlLS <<< I just put it at the bottom.

Comment: Ok but don't select the empty columns for the Chart Just select The Type and the Sum only you can select the first Column, press Ctrl and select the sum column to draw the chart

Comment: Okay, thank you for that note. Updated and added a photo of completed chart if anyone in the future needs to reference post. http://imgur.com/VBAWtur

Comment: Very clear Chart if you are satisfied kindly click on the answer to accept it and Thank You

Comment: @Sam Hey I would if I could, I am a newbie check out my profile. I can't do squat atm. Sorry, I'll add your name to the post so users can upvote.

Comment: @JoseLeyva: you can still accept Sam's answer, please do it to mark it as a solution.

Comment: @MátéJuhász not sure how to do that?

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, just click on the check mark beside it, only the owner of the question can do it

Comment: @Sam hmmm, I had awhile ago. Not sure if that is visible?

Comment: @Sam Thank You for the help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy Type Column and paste it 2 columns after your original Data then remove Duplicates from Data Tab you will have your 4 categories alone, in the cell near US Stocks use the following formula in G2:
**=SUMIF($A$2:$A$16,F2,$B$2:$B$16)**
$A$2:$A$16 is where your Type is with repeated category in the original Table and $B$2:$B$16 is your Market Value also in the original Table and F2 is the new Us Stocks after removing duplicates.

[image: My Chart]